# Dividir a tela do aplicativo em dois layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou querendo dividir a tela do celular ao meio.

Tenho dois `LinearLayout` com o mesmo tamanho, mas parece que o único jeito de fazer isso, é colocando o tamanho na propriedade `android:layout_height=<tamanho>`?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_id"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
tools:context=".MyActivity">


  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Esse é o meu `layout.xml`, quero deixar os dois `LinearLayout` internos com a mesma altura.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você consegue trabalhar dessa forma usando o atributo `weight` (Peso).

Observe o código abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" >  //Peso total do Layout


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"> //Esse Layout pesa 50% do Layout total

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"> //Esse Layout pesa 50% do Layout total

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

No `LinearLayout` principal, foi definido que o `weight` é 1 e nos `LinearLayout` mais internos, foram definidos que cada um tem metade do peso do Layout principal.
(Coloquei os dois `TextView`'s apenas para melhor visualizar o resultado)

Observe o resultado:

[image: Observe as marcações de limite dos layouts]